# Date not displaying in Textbox if TextMode is set to "Date"?

Tags: html, sql, vb.net, datepicker

I have three textboxes: tbEditStartDate, tbEditStopDate, and tbEditRenewalDate. I have a Gridview called gvApp which contains a list of applicants with their start date, stop date, and renewal date. I've created a Row Command which I use to pull the start date, stop date, and renewal date and display it in tbEditStartDate, tbStopDate, and tbRenewalDate. My issue is that whenever I include Textmode="Date" to the textboxes, the dates would not display. If I remove TextMode="Date", the dates display. I'm try to to keep TextMode="Date" because the DatePicker makes it easier for users to pick dates visually. Also, I've tried changing the data types of the three values in SQL but still no luck. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="row view-basic-card" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        Start Date:
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbEditStartDate" class="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        Stop Date:
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbEditStopDate" class="form-control" textmode="date" runat="server"  Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        Renewal Date:
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbEditRenewalDate" class="form-control" runat="server"  Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        Contract Type:
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbEditContractType" class="form-control" runat="server" Style="margin-right: 15px; width: 185px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then here's my row command:

```
Protected Sub gvApp_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

Dim myDateTime As Date = Date.Parse(DateString)
Dim myDate As Date = myDateTime.Date()

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strSelectedPersonID As String
Dim strSelectedFirstname As String
Dim strSelectedLastname As String
Dim strSelectedMiddlename As String
Dim strSelectPosition As String
Dim strEditDepartment As String
Dim strEditBirthdate As String = myDate
Dim strEditGender As String
Dim strEditCitizenship As String
Dim strEditSSN As String
Dim strEditPassport As String
Dim strEditVisa As String
Dim strEditPhone As String
Dim strEditEmail As String
Dim strEditAddress As String
Dim strOfferLetterStatus As String
Dim strOfferStatusDate As String
Dim strEditStartDate As String = myDate
Dim strEditStopDate As String = myDate
Dim strEditRenewalDate As String = myDate
Dim strEditContractType As String
Dim strEditAvailDate As String = myDate
Dim strEditArrivalDate As String = myDate

If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
    idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

    Dim row As GridViewRow = gvApp.Rows(idx)

    xSelectedPersonID = row.Cells(0).Text

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HRRecruitmentDBConn").ToString())

        conn.Open()
        Dim dsApplicant As New DataSet()
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader

        Dim strSelectCmd As String = "SELECT * FROM tblApplicant WHERE AppID = @AppID "
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSelectCmd, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppID", xSelectedPersonID)
        cmd.Connection = conn
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows Then

            While (dr.Read())
                strEditStartDate = dr(1).ToString
                strEditStopDate = dr(2).ToString
                strEditRenewalDate = dr(3).ToString
                strEditContractType = dr(4).ToString

                strEditDepartment = dr(7).ToString
                strSelectPosition = dr(6).ToString
                strSelectedFirstname = dr(8).ToString
                strSelectedLastname = dr(9).ToString
                strSelectedMiddlename = dr(10).ToString
                strEditGender = dr(11).ToString
                strEditBirthdate = dr(12).ToString

                strEditEmail = dr(13).ToString
                strEditPhone = dr(14).ToString
                strEditAddress = dr(15).ToString
                strEditSSN = dr(16).ToString
                strEditPassport = dr(17).ToString

                strEditCitizenship = dr(18).ToString
                strEditVisa = dr(19).ToString
                strOfferLetterStatus = dr(20).ToString
                strOfferStatusDate = dr(21).ToString

                strEditAvailDate = dr(23).ToString
                strEditArrivalDate = dr(24).ToString

            End While

        End If

        tbEditStartDate.Text = strEditStartDate
        tbEditStopDate.Text = strEditStopDate
        tbEditRenewalDate.Text = strEditRenewalDate
        tbEditContractType.Text = strEditContractType
        cmbAppEditPosition.Value = strSelectPosition
        cmbEditDepartment.Value = strEditDepartment
        tbEditFirstname.Text = strSelectedFirstname
        tbEditLastname.Text = strSelectedLastname
        tbEditMiddlename.Text = strSelectedMiddlename
        cmbEditGender.Value = strEditGender
        tbEditBirthdate.Text = strEditBirthdate
        tbEditEmail.Text = strEditEmail
        tbEditPhone.Text = strEditPhone
        tbEditAddress.Text = strEditAddress
        tbEditSSN.Text = strEditSSN
        tbEditPassport.Text = strEditPassport
        tbEditCitizenship.Text = strEditCitizenship
        tbEditVisa.Text = strEditVisa
        cmbOfferStatus.Value = strOfferLetterStatus
        tbOfferStatusDate.Text = strOfferStatusDate
        tbEditAvailDate.Text = strEditAvailDate
        tbEditArrivalDate.Text = strEditArrivalDate

        conn.Close()


    End Using



End If

BindGridView()
```

End Sub

Comment: It should be fairly obvious that posting that has a huge wad of leading whitespace on every line but the first is far from ideal. It's very easy to avoid doing that using either VS or the editor in this site so please don't do it again. Please do everything you can to help us help you and posting easily readable code is something you can do easily.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for you response. My apologies but how do I that through the site's editor? I've removed some code lines and some whitespaces in between them.

Comment: I just selected all but the first line of you HTML and clicked the code button to outdent it four spaces at a time. If you're copying from VS though, just hold down the Alt key as you select a block and you can avoid selecting all the whitespace to begin with.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you. I followed your directions for copying from VS.

Answer (score 0):

You are holding your connection open way too long. Don't open your connection until just before the .Execute. Close the connection as soon as possible. Don't update the user interface while the connection is open.

The End Using closes and disposes both the connection and the command.

Instead of all those variables, just assign the values from the DataTable directly to the UI control properties.

For text controls with the attribute TextMode="Date" call .ToString("yyy-MM-dd") on a DateTime object.

```
Protected Sub gvApp_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        Dim row As GridViewRow = gvApp.Rows(CInt(e.CommandArgument))
        Dim xSelectedPersonID = row.Cells(0).Text
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HRRecruitmentDBConn").ToString),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblApplicant WHERE AppID = @AppID ", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = xSelectedPersonID
            conn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            tbEditStartDate.Text = CDate(dt.Rows(0)(1)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            tbEditStopDate.Text = CDate(dt.Rows(0)(2)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            tbEditRenewalDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString
            tbEditContractType.Text = dt.Rows(0)(4).ToString

            cmbEditDepartment.Value = dt.Rows(0)(7).ToString
            cmbAppEditPosition.Value = dt.Rows(0)(6).ToString
            tbEditFirstname.Text = dt.Rows(0)(8).ToString
            tbEditLastname.Text = dt.Rows(0)(9).ToString
            tbEditMiddlename.Text = dt.Rows(0)(10).ToString
            cmbEditGender.Value = dt.Rows(0)(11).ToString
            tbEditBirthdate.Text = dt.Rows(0)(12).ToString

            tbEditEmail.Text = dt.Rows(0)(13).ToString
            tbEditPhone.Text = dt.Rows(0)(14).ToString
            tbEditAddress.Text = dt.Rows(0)(15).ToString
            tbEditSSN.Text = dt.Rows(0)(16).ToString
            tbEditPassport.Text = dt.Rows(0)(17).ToString

            tbEditCitizenship.Text = dt.Rows(0)(18).ToString
            tbEditVisa.Text = dt.Rows(0)(19).ToString
            cmbOfferStatus.Value = dt.Rows(0)(20).ToString
            tbOfferStatusDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)(21).ToString

            tbEditAvailDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)(23).ToString
            tbEditArrivalDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)(24).ToString
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```